# Filesize limit in reading files with node.js and serving output as HTTP response expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code for node.js and expressjs:

```
app.get('/api/csv/:filename', function (req, res) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var csvData = fs.readFileSync("public/uploads/"+req.params.filename, 'utf8');
    res.send(csvData);
});
```

this works fine for small-ish files say up to 100-200MB as I've tested (not sure about the max/highest size, it was in that range. Anything bigger say 300+MB and it fails.

The node.js code / expressjs returns error like:

```
#
# Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/handles.h, line 48
# CHECK(location_ != NULL) failed
#

==== C stack trace ===============================

1: ??
2: ??
3: ??
4: ??
5: ??
6: ??
7: ??
Illegal instruction: 4
```

I suspect this is issue with node.js fs.readFileSync() and storing output in a variable rather than expressjs? I'm currently using node.js v0.12.4.

How might I rework the code to have it be able to return huge files as a string of text over HTTP?

As to the error message, I would have thought it should return something like out of memory, sadly rather cryptic output.

Comment: Do you really need to send the whole dataset to the client? You probably should consider filtering and aggregating the csv file's data on the server, and sending only the actually needed data client-side.

Comment: You may want to upgrade to a newer version of node.js. cf. [LTS schedule](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `Readable stream`, and assigning an event listener:

```
const readable = fs.createReadStream("public/uploads/" + req.params.filename);
readable.on('data', (chunk) => {
  res.write(chunk);
});
readable.on('end', () => {
  res.end();
});
```

I never actually tried that, but it should work.

Comment: Does this require specific version of node? Or specific module dependencies? Using the snippet inside an app.get() route returns this on server startup: `readable.on('data', (chunk) => {
                                ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>` where the error in question is the `=>`.

Comment: Try replacing by `function(chunk) { ... }`. Using `stream.pipe` is actually perfect.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Still get the client side d3.csv() issue that I get with stream pipe though :(

Comment: What happens if you parse the csv server-side to JSON and use the JSON in your client?

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe to the response:

```
var fs = require('fs');
app.get('/api/csv/:filename', function (req, res) {
  var filepath = "public/uploads/"+req.params.filename
  var stream = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
  stream.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to kind of work. Now I have to see how I can handle all that data on the client side with d3.js. It works fine for 100-200 MB of data, but seems to not parse right using your solution.

Comment: FYI, parsing the CSV client side with d3.csv(), see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/ERPsoQcgJiU

Comment: @David you can also try using [`res.sendFile()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) depending on your version of express.